# Einstein manifolds and topology

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, compact-manifolds

Given a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ with Ricci tensor $ R_{mn} = k g_{mn} $. Suppose the Ricci scalar you get is

$$ R > 0 $$

What can you tell about the manifold $globally$ ? In particular, can you say anything about the **topology** of this manifold (e.g is this compact?) ?

This question arise in a Physics situation: in 11-dimensional supergravity, one can find solutions to equations with a factorised metric describing $M_4 \times M_7$, where the Riemannian manifold $M_7$ has the geometry described above (Einstein manifold with positive Ricci curvature). These solutions are said to furnish a *spontaneous conpactification* because $M_7$ is "automatically" compact. But I don't really understand why this is the case.

PS: Useful references where to study these topics in differential geometry? I just know basics (in order to understand General Relativity and String Theory)

Comment: Regarding references, _Einstein Manifolds_ by A. Besse is worth a look (despite its age) if you have access to a university library.

Answer (score 4):

[Myers's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers's_theorem) says that if a manifold has positive lower bound for Ricci curvature, then it must be compact. In particular, if $M$ is Einstein with positive scalar curvature, we have 
$$Ric=\frac{R}{n}g.$$
Note that Einstein manifold must have constant scalar curvature (which follows from Bianchi identity). 
Combining all these, we can conclude that $M$ is compact.

Comment: Isn't that the constant scalar curvature follows from the equation $\text{Ric} = kg$?

Comment: Yes. It really depends on your definition of Einstein manifold. You can define Einstein manifold to satisfy $Ric=kg$ for some constant $k$. Or you can define Einstein manifold to satisfy $Ric=\frac{R}{n}g$, or equivalently, the traceless Einstein tensor is zero. But they are equivalent by the Bianchi identity, at least for $n\geq 3$.

Comment: In Myers's theorem, completeness is an important assumption too (otherwise, of course, one could say take a round sphere minus a point, this is Einstein with positive scalar curvature and it is non-compact).